# how to iterate over items in dictionary using while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

i know how to iterate over items in dictionary using for loop. but **i need know is how to iterate over items in dictionary using while loop**. is that possible?

This how i tried it with for loop.

```
user_info = {
    "username" : "Hansana123",
    "password" : "1234",
    "user_id" : 3456,
    "reg_date" : "Nov 19"
}


for values,keys in user_info.items():
    print(values, "=", keys)
```

Comment: if useful kindly check it correct

Comment: You can iter() the list of items(). You can iter() the view of dict.keys() - in any case you are not itereating the dict directly. Using a for loop over the keys() ( or items() if you need key + value) is the way to go.  Restricting it to a while .... sounds like a restriction based on badly posed homework tasks to me ...

Comment: Any specific reason for using ```while``` loop ? Generally  a ```while``` loop is used when you don't know the number of iterations and should keep looping until a condition is met. I don't see any use-case where ```while``` loop is used to ```iterate``` over a dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can iterate the items of a dictionary using `iter` and `next` with a `while` loop. This is **almost** the same process as how a `for` loop would perform the iteration in the background on any iterable.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

Code:

```
user_info = {
    "username" : "Hansana123",
    "password" : "1234",
    "user_id" : 3456,
    "reg_date" : "Nov 19"
}

print("Using for loop...")
for key, value in user_info.items():
    print(key, "=", value)

print()

print("Using while loop...")
it_dict = iter(user_info.items())
while key_value := next(it_dict, None):
    print(key_value[0], "=", key_value[1])
```

Output:

```
Using for loop...
username = Hansana123
password = 1234
user_id = 3456
reg_date = Nov 19

Using while loop...
username = Hansana123
password = 1234
user_id = 3456
reg_date = Nov 19
```

Comment: "This is just the same process" – almost the same process. A `for` loop wouldn't use the sentinel value for `next()`, it'd catch the `StopIteration` instead.

Comment: Good find! Agree. I would update the answer to avoid confusion. Thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 3):

this is not perfect solution which I did but it is in while loop

```
user_info = {
    "username" : "Hansana123",
    "password" : "1234",
    "user_id" : 3456,
    "reg_date" : "Nov 19"
}

i = 0
length = len(list(user_info.items()))
keys, values = list(user_info.keys()), list(user_info.values())

while i < length:
    print(values[i], "=", keys[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: you are actually iterating over list indirectly that true that you can't iterate dict directly without changing datatype

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Thank you for posting your attempt, but this doesn't seem to exactly answer the question. You might want to explore a little bittle more on the dictionary data type and revise your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate over dict using while loop if acessing while loop because dict elements are unordered and in a while loop you can only access on iterables like str list tuples only by index and dict have no indexes. I hope it will clarify your Question.

Comment: I'm still a begginer in python. Thank you so much for your help... I will find out more about that. ; )